# The Sun's location in noon and tropic of Cancer/Capricorn

Tags: sun

I came across this [article](https://study.com/academy/lesson/importance-of-the-tropic-of-cancer-the-tropic-of-capricorn.html) and I would like to clarify a few moments:

> if you're located north of the Tropic of Cancer, the Sun will always
> appear south of the zenith.

Does it mean if I am located north of the Tropic of Cancer and I point a compass to the Sun at noon, the Sun will alway be in south.

And the same for the Tropic of Capricorn:

> if you're somewhere south of the Tropic of Capricorn, the Sun appears to be always north of the zenith

If I am located south of the Tropic of Capricorn and I point a compass to the Sun at noon, the Sun will alway be in north.

Comment: How does this question differ from the question: here? https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24696/tropic-of-cancer-capricorn-and-sun-position

Comment: Pacman, please stop asking the same questions... https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24696/tropic-of-cancer-capricorn-and-sun-position is basically the same question as far as I can tell from a couple weeks ago.  You can click on your user name to see your account details, which will include a list of your other questions.  If you were wanting to update that question, click edit on it.

Comment: you can find all the information you want here:https://www.timeanddate.com/ it is a good source for information about our sun-earth-moon.